# How do I refer to my defined queue in yaml

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless

I have: (I am using serverless-lift plugin here):

```
constructs:
  my-queue:
    type: queue
    worker:
      handler: src/handlers/my-queue.handler
```

For IAM I have:

```
SqsQueueIam:
  Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - sqs:*
  Resource:
    Fn::GetAtt: [constructs.my-queue, Arn]
    Fn::GetAtt: [${self:constructs.my-queue}, Arn] // does not work either
```

This results in template error during deploy. What am I doing wrong ? I am noob in regards to cloud formation...

Can you help

EDIT:
even if I add sth like this, it returns access denied:

```
SqsQueueIam:
  Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - sqs:*
  Resource: "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the documented variables?

https://github.com/getlift/lift/blob/master/docs/queue.md#variables

something like

```
- Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - sqs:SendMessage
      Resource:
        Fn::GetAtt: [construct:my-queue, queueArn]
```